# Check my form - 8 point block

Tags: karate, blocking

I'm a new Karateka, practicing Chinese Goju Ryu and I'm working on my 8 point blocking system.

I'm hoping that someone can give me an opinion of my form.

(Constructive answers and comments only please)

https://youtu.be/R7qnvjpHAW0

Arigatou gozaimasu!

Comment: Please try to narrow your inquiry and ask a specific question. Otherwise I think the responses you get will essentially reduce to "your style is not like my style".  This question might be OK if everyone studied in your school, but that's not the case here.

Comment: My comment is: Keep practicing and get correction from your instructors. Right now, you have not committed any of it to memory (as evidence by you hesitating to remember the next move). You lack lower body coordination with the upper body, and therefore you have poor balance and poor power. Your blocking surfaces often appear to be the padded sides of your forearm, and some would say that's fine, others will say use the bone instead (think of them like counter-strikes, not just blocks). Lastly, there's no snap in your fists. Basically, you're a novice. Good start. Now keep practicing it.

Comment: It's very unproductive to ask for form correction on the internets.  An instructor can do for you in 10 minutes what we would spend hours trying to accomplish and still fail at.

Answer (score 0):

As already has been stated, your question asks for opinions,  and is vague and not very well suited for this forum.

I watched your video,  and would say that firstly,  your hikite should be on the side of your body,  not under your breast. Secondly,  your gedan harai uke is too linear,  and should be a movement  where you start with your fist up,  forearm perpendicular to the floor,  upper arm parallel to the floor,  move your elbow in front of your body,  and swing forearm and fist (ken) down,  stopping in front of your thigh,  with a fist width from thigh to fist.

The next advice I have for you is to ask a sempai / your sensei to show you,  and if you want to practice for yourself,  ask permission to film them,  then film yourself,  and compare.